# Complex object sent to web api angular 4

Tags: angular, http, typescript, asp.net-web-api, request

I'm trying to make a put request with the new HttpClient and HttpParams but it seems i can't send properly the updated object. I'm trying to put the object as a parameter like this :[This is where i make my request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vt1ee.png) and this is my class : [myclass](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpv0o.png) those are he request headers [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BrCGS.png) and the params section :[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Go8Rh.png) the request response throws null reference exception because it can't map them i guess ?

Comment: Please post code and message as text instead of screenshots. [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HttpParams should be [3rd argument](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#put). So you should call put like this:

```
this.http.put(this.url, myComplexObject, this.options);
```

Comment: Yep that was it. Thanks so much. Guess it was a noobie question :)

Comment: Sometimes third eyes help :)